# Determinant of Matrix combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I have got a big Matrix with the structure
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
  A_1 & A_2 \\
  A_2^{T} & A_4 \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $A_{1}$ equals a Matrix full of zeros. $A_{2}$,$A_{3}$ and $A_{4}$ can have any values. If $A_{2}$ is fixed - Is there always an option to set $A_{4}$ to get at least one negative Eigenvalue?
The Problem is that $A_{2}$ does not need to be a square Matrix so
$$
det(A-\lambda I) =\begin{pmatrix}
  -\lambda I_s & A_2 \\
  A_2^{T} & A_4-\lambda I_k \\
 \end{pmatrix} \ne -\lambda I_s * (A_4-\lambda I_k)- A_2 * A_2^{T}
$$
will not work.
With $k,s$ for the size of the $I$-Matrix.
Moreover because the Matrix is too big I cannot check or guarantee that it is Invertible.

Comment: Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

For example

> $$
> \left(
> \begin{array}{c|cc}
> 0 & 1 & 1\\
> \hline
> 1 & 1 & 0\\
> 1 & 0 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right)
> $$

has the eigenvalue

> $$
> 2, -1, +1.
> $$

Thus

> $$
> A_2 = \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right),
> A_3 = \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
> 1\\
> 1
> \end{array}
> \right),
> A_4 = \left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 0\\
> 0 & 1
> \end{array}
> \right).
> $$

Note that
$$
\det A_2 = \det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
\det A_3 = \det \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
are NOT defined!